# What to do after a social engineering attack was used to trick utility services at my hypothetical business? How to close the security hole?

Tags: social-engineering, business-risk

**Business Attack Scenario**

> Standard information that was ubiquitous through my chain-businesses
>   was exploited by a rogue group of former employees to sabotage. They
>   considered manipulating all serial numbers and phone numbers that they
>   can use to trick utility services into electronically resetting cable
>   and the internet at businesses.
>
> Emails are being received from other chain locations of my business
>   reporting managers' alleged frivolous behaviors. Frivolous spam calls
>   are harassing my human resources headquarters. Fax machines have been
>   exploited to harass my employees with indecent images or threats.
>
> They have gotten into my voice message system by resetting the password
>   multiple times slowing down customer service.
>
> My sales were disrupted and customers were unsatisfied. I lost
>   thousands in days. I've been receiving calls for service on my DVR
>   system that I use for my security cameras. Fake orders are being
>   placed on my website affecting legitimate customers and slowing down
>   their orders.
>
> DVR security systems connected to the internet were penetrated. Video
>   footage was erased on the hard-drives after one chain location was
>   robbed and thousands went missing at 3 am in the mourning.

*What type of businesses would be employed to protect my business from an unlikely attack?
How do these services perform to protect businesses harassed like this?
What type of security procedures should be used to prevent this scenario?*

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: "prosecute to the fullest extent of the law" is probably your best bet here.